# pagination with kaminari and mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, kaminari

I have this problem

```
undefined method `total_pages' for
# <Mongoid::Criteria:0x00000002651d80>

# controller
@services = Service.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 3)

# view
<% paginate @services %>
```

The mongo doesn't return the object.

Comment: Post what you have done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In kaminari, you have to 
use below syntax

```
 Service.page(params[:page].to_i).per(3)
```

instead of

```
 Service.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 3)
```

This is the syntax of will_paginate

Comment: Great, the problem now, the paginate no return elements as determinate in  Service.page(params[:page].to_i).per(3).

Comment: @CarlosAndré Did this solution helped ? if yes the accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Controler

```html
class ServicesController < ApplicationController
 def index
  #@services = Service.order(name: :asc)
  @organs = Admin::Organ.all
  @services = Service.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 3)
 
 end
end
```

```html
<% pagination @services %>
```

Erro

```html
undefined method `total_pages' for #<Mongoid::Criteria:0x00000002651d80>
```

was this